# How to decrement amount after form submit in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

> I am checking the amount of the user's wallet first. That the fee to
> fill a form is not less than that in the user's wallet. If there is sufficient amount in the user's wallet. Then the form is submitted and whatever form is the fee. Be less than the wallet of the user.
> **For example, after paying with paytm, the amount from our wallet is reduced.**

```
 router.post(
  '/create'
  async (req, res) => {
    try {

      //First I have checked. That is how much money.

    const userw = await users.findOne().select('-password');
      if (userw.totleAmount < userw.panrate) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: [{ msg: 'Your amount is less than 110. Please add the amount.' }] })
      }
      const user = await users.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
      const newPan = new Pan({
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        imagepath: image.tempFilePath,
        username: user.username,
        avatar: user.avatar,
        totleAmount: userw.totleAmount,
        panrate: userw.panrate,
        user: req.user.id,
      });

      //And if there is money. Then the form is submitted,
      //But I want that when the status of submitting the form comes to 200 then the amount of 
      //filling the form from the user's wallet should be reduced.

    const pan = await newPan.save();
      if (res.status === 200) {
          userw.totleAmount-userw.panrate
          res.json({ panData: pan, msg: 'New Pan card Created' });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this using mongoose ,just add a callback like this in save callback:

```
const pan = await newPan.save((err, newPan, isSaveSuccessful)=>{

  if(err){ return next(err); } 

  if (isSaveSuccessful === 1){ 

  // newPan has been saved correctly 

  // do stuff with the saved documentFoo 

  userw.totleAmount=userw.totleAmount-userw.panrate

  } 
}
```